# How do you break long string lines in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, newline, escaping, line-breaks, long-lines

For example, I want to break the long string in the below panic statement:
`(panic "Truth-assignment length is longer than the number of propositions!")`
I have tried
`(panic "Truth-assignment length is longer than the number \`
`of propositions!")`
and
`(panic "Truth-assignment length is longer than the number`
`of propositions!")`
and they both don't work. Googling hasn't turned up anything either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use string-append with the built-in formatting of your IDE:

```
(panic (string-append "Truth-assignment length is longer " 
                      "than the number of propositions!"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all Scheme specifications define a way to break long strings. The answer to your question depends on which Scheme you are using. I believe R6RS includes a method like the first one you tried. Others might provide no such option, forcing you to either reduce the length of your strings, have very long lines, or use string-append with smaller strings.

Have a look at these links:
http://www.mail-archive.com/r6rs-discuss@lists.r6rs.org/msg01810.html
http://practical-scheme.net/gauche/ (search for 2008/2/13)